# How to get only one random element from object?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

My model.py is this.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country_fact = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    country_capital = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country_flags = models.ImageField(upload_to='flags')
```

View.py is this

```
def index(request):
    country = Country.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'country':country})
```

I'm retrieving those data in HTML by using this

```
{% for count in country %}
 <img src="{{ count.country_flags.url }}">
```

This retrieves all the country images from the database(I'm using Postgresql). I want to retrieve only one random country flag from the database. How can I achieve this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can use `import random` `random.choice(list)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def index(request):

    country = Country.objects.all()
    choosen = random.choice(country)


    context = {
        'country': country,
        'choosen': choosen
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```